# Would it be nice to gain reputation through individual comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have noticed the difficulty in earning reputation points and also the reason; however, a couple of times, people are able to help and even solve some problems just by a simple comment. Just like on [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook), where we can reply and like comments, Stack Overflow could use the same system and motivate more people to help and stay active while gaining confidence with their own career as programmers.

Comment: I don't think it would encourage the right behavior or solve any problems.

Comment: How does this help you - you don't have enough reputation to comment yet?

Comment: Well, it sounds OK for gaining rep, but such a scheme would inevitably lead to some mechanism for LOSING points for comments that the OP does not like, and then I will have no rep:(

Comment: Just keep in mind we're not like facebook ... not at all ... assuming that features they have would work for Stack Overflow is just wrong.

Comment: Wow 37 downvotes (6/16/2020)!! This may not be an excellent question, in fact it is not even a question, but hey the man is making a legit point!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Just like on Facebook

[Noooooooo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlqYW.jpg) Stack Overflow is not designed to be Facebook-like. Comments are temporary and can be removed at any point.

If a question is answered in the comments there are two possible solutions:

- The comment, and probably entire comment thread, should be condensed into a real answer and posted as such
- The question should be closed (likely because the problem was a typo)

> Stack Overflow could [...] motivate more people to help and stay active while gaining confidence with their own career as programmers.

This is accomplished through existing functionality. Post a good question. Post a good answer. Both of those options allow you to learn more about your chosen profession. If you aren't confident enough to do either, stretch your inner English professor by editing posts to be more clear. That will increase your reputation here too.

Posting a witty comment so that it gets upvoted is not the way to gain reputation on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15):

The current system works exactly as it should.

Real answers are *serious* - you make a claim, and the community will judge you for it.

Answers in *comments*, on the other hand, are fleeting thoughts, "try this"-type advice, ideas that you aren't quite sure about or don't want to take responsibility for (like in an answer, where you could be called out or downvoted).

Generally, you don't want to *encourage* people answering in comments because there are no quality control tools like there are for answers.

- Comments are short.
- You can't link to sources.
- They can't be improved by other community members.

I (like many others) frequently give answers in comments - for example when I can't be bothered to do enough research to provide an answer, or when I think the question is too simple, or a duplicate, but I don't want to look for the original question.

I don't earn any rep for those comments. Anyone else can take the comment and make it into a *real* answer and earn rep for it.

That's exactly how it should be.